# Where is documentation for jetty 8 xml contexts?

Tags: jetty

Does anyone know where the documentation or tutorial would be for how to make xml contexts in jetty 7/8? for example:

```
> <contextHandlers> <contextHandler
> implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
> <contextPath>/w3c</contextPath> <resourceBase><SystemProperty
> name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/w3c</resourceBase> <handler
> implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler"/>
> </contextHandler> </contextHandlers>
```

Where is documentation on how to create this?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/ContextDeployer